# Session closed instead of shutdown

Tags: power-management, shutdown, 16.04

Shutdown from taskbar, but instead session is closed. Why?

I have to "poweroff" in terminal.

Desktop computer running Ubuntu 16.04, recently upgraded from 15.10 (not sure, but I believe also happened).

Thanks.

Comment: Could be a bug, report to Unity's Launchpad page

Comment: It gradually stopped happening and have not experienced it for a long time after some system updates, and also bios update.

Comment: Probably got fixed with one of the updates. Glad it works for you now !